# d3.tree scrollbar instead of panning

Tags: d3.js, scroll, panning

I have a tree width d3.js. when tree overflows svg, it is hidden and I can view hidden parts by panning on tree. is there any way to add scrollbar for view hidden parts instead of panning?
for example in this sample http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033 I want to add scroll bar to this tree. this sample is not what I want: https://bl.ocks.org/CrandellWS/ca7e6626c9e6b1413963
because in this example when we collapse nodes, scrollbar size not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the svg bounding box using `svg.getBBox()`, where `svg` is your svg node, e.g.

```
let svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
let box = svg.getBBox()
```

and then use `box.x`, `.y`, `.width` and `.height` to calculate the correct `viewBox` attribute value, width and height.